# How to include new columns in JIRA help center requests?

Tags: jira

I am trying to add new columns to the JIRA help center requests, but I am not sure how to do it. I have tried to follow the instructions on the JIRA website, but I am still having trouble. Can anyone help me?

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ieocv.png)

I am trying to add a custom field to Jira help center requests. The custom field exists and has been created successfully, but it is not appearing as an option to be selected and displayed in the table.